# Can you add/remove required RubyGems programmatically in Ruby or as a command line arg?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a test suite that is designed to run locally and on a cloud vendor. When the test is run locally I would like to use a RubyGem that makes use of native extensions that run much faster. On the cloud vendor however, I cannot include this particular flavour of gem and must use a different one.

Is there a way that I can, either by command line argument, or as a function in Ruby add or remove gem requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `require` statements inside an `if/else`.

```
if `hostname`.strip == 'local'
    require 'ruby_ext_gem'
else
    require 'ruby_native_gem'
end
```

Or run the Ruby interpreter with the `-r` option.

```
ruby -rruby_ext_gem -rruby_ext_gem2 script.rb
```

Maybe [`bundler`](http://bundler.io/) would be what you are searching for?

```
#Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org'
group 'local' do
  gem 'ruby_ext_gem'
  gem 'ruby-ldap', require: 'ldap'
end

group 'cloud' do
  gem 'ruby_native_gem'
  gem 'ruby-net-ldap', require: 'net/ldap'
end

# local
bundle install --without cloud
# cloud
bundle install --without local

#script.rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(`hostname`.strip)
```